# Typescript any number except X

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-typings, discriminator

TLDR:

**Is this type possible somehow in TS? `Exclude<number, 200 | 400>` ("any number except 200 or 400")**

I have the following use case. I have a response type, which is generic:

```
type HttpResponse<Body = any, StatusCode = number> = {
  body: Body
  statusCode: StatusCode
}
```

And I'd like to use the status code as a discriminator:

```
// Succes
type SuccessResponse = HttpResponse<SomeType, 200>
// Known error
type ClientErrorResponse = HttpResponse<ClientError, 400>
// Anything else, generic error, issue is with the status code here.
type OtherErrorResponse = HttpResponse<GenericError, Exclude<number, 200 | 400>>

// The response type is a union of the above
type MyResponse = SuccessResponse | ClientErrorResponse | OtherErrorResponse
```

When I use the `MyResponse` type, I'd like to use the status code as a discriminator, eg.:

```
const response: MyResponse = ...

if(response.statusCode === 200) {
  // response is inferred as SuccessResponse => body is inferred as SomeType
} else if(response.statusCode === 400) {
  // response is inferred as ClientErrorResponse => body is inferred as ClientError
} else {
  // response is inferred as OtherErrorResponse => body is inferred as GenericError
}
```

However it doesn't work like this as `Exclude<number, 200 | 400>` is the same as just `number`. How do I solve this? Is the type `"any number except 200 or 400"` possible with typescript? Any other creative solutions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible at the moment.

See: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15480

---

`Exclude<number, 200 | 400>` doesn't work because typescript tracks only what something *is*, and never tracks what it *is not*. To so make excluding some values from an infinite series work, typescript would have to generate a union with every single possible value, except for the ones you wish to exclude. This would be a union of infinite length (since Infinity minus 2 equals Infinity)

---

That said, the list of http status codes is actually finite. So the best way is probably to create a union of all *possible* values and use that:

```
type HTTPStatusCode = 100 | 101 | 102 | 103 | 200 | 201 | 202 | ...
```

Now this should work fine:

```
Exclude<HTTPStatusCode, 200 | 400>
```

Comment: It's not really an infinite set. Numbers in JavaScript are 64-bit floats so there are a finite (very large but finite) number of possible values. So it seems possible that #15480 might be implemented one day. Although it is much simpler to consider `number` to be an infinite set (as the compiler currently does).

Comment: While not wrong, it is conceptually infinite, storing all possible values of `number` in memory would take over 17GB (`4,294,967,295*32/8)`. If Typescript implements negated types, this case would definitely not implemented by treating `number` as a finite union.

Comment: There would be no need to store every value. You could use a range or a sequence of ranges. Although I don't immediately see how the finite nature of floats would affect that implementation. I mean, if you're using ranges, then does it matter if there are finite or infinite values within the range? So you're right. It probably doesn't matter.